# htaccess rewrite rule not passing url vars when script file is same as rewrite directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to create nice urls with .htaccess files and have come across a weird issue.

I want to change `portfolio.php?id=2` to `/portfolio/2/`

seems pretty simple solution

`RewriteRule ^portfolio/([0-9]+)/$ /portfolio.php?id=$1 [L]`

this does redirect to the correct script but when i try and run `<?=$_GET['id'];?>` it is undefined. but if change the script to something that does not equal the fake directory it works.

`RewriteRule ^portfolio/([0-9]+)/$ /portfolioitem.php?id=$1 [L]`

and just to make sure that it wasn't being caught by any other rules I tested this

`RewriteRule ^portfolioitem/([0-9]+)/$ /portfolioitem.php?id=$1 [L]`

and again it failed to pick up the id paramater!

any ideas?!

Cheers

Comment: Have you tried it without the end slash, like, `RewriteRule ^portfolio/([0-9]+)$ /portfolio.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]`?

Comment: Yes, that has the same results! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds suspiciously like a [Multiviews](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html#negotiation) related problem coupled with some `PATH_INFO`. The `Multiviews` option is part of mod_negotiation and it will try to match a requested URL path to a file path. It sees:

```
/portfolio/2/
```

And sees that there's a `/portfolio.php` file in the filesystem and assumes that this is what you want (which it is, but not in the same way). I'm willing to bet that instead of looking at `$_GET['id']`, which is blank of course since there are no GET params, if you look at `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`, you'll see it set to `/2/`. This is equivalent to going to:

```
/portfolio.php/2/
```

where the `/2/` part gets passed to **portfolio.php** as part of the `PATH_INFO`. And since mod_negotiation is further up in the processing pipeline than mod_rewrite, your rewrite rules never get applied.

Try turning off multiviews. You can do this in your htaccess file using the [`Options`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options) directive (assuming your host has allowed Options):

```
Options -Multiviews
```